# How conditional are conditional offers

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I've already accepted an offer from my dream school for a phD program and already set up rotations with professors. I was accepted on a conditional offer though and am now 0.4% below the average they stated I must maintain in my final year (or offer may be rescinded). Is there a high chance that they'll take back the offer? I know they can, but has anyone ever heard of this happening? I'm reluctant to contact the program directly (although I know I must) because the person in charge of making admissions decisions just so happens to be the person I want to be my future advisor...and I would hate to start the relationship in such a negative way.

Comment: Depends on the specific program, I'm afraid.

Comment: Just contact the person and get it sorted out. I find it unlikely they'll rescind the offer for such a small difference in their standard and your average. And if they will rescind, it benefits you to learn about this as early as possible.

Comment: "How conditional are conditional offers?"  It depends!

Answer (score 11):

An awfully far worse way to start the relationship would be to not be able to start that relationship. Please do yourself a favor and bite the bullet, contact the relevant person right away and calmly explain your current lapse/fear -  then listen carefully to what they tell you. There is no standard or law on how to handle such a situation, the program is likely able to do pretty much whatever it wants. The sooner you find something out the more time you have to work with to try to work something out - or to at least be able to relax!

I'd go so far as to say that if someone outside your program tells you with any certainty whether or not such an offer will be rescinded or not, you really should ignore them utterly - talk with your program! Every University, department, and program is pretty unique unto itself in questions of graduate school admission.

This is just one of those things best handled directly with the responsible persons, as advice in this form is worth it's mass in gold. Good luck - deep breaths!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think this was one of those instances where I already knew what I needed to do (contact the program), but was trying to put that off as much as possible. I did end up emailing them though, and basically got a slap on the hand, but they will not be revoking the offer. Now I just need to work my butt off in grad school to prove myself, which I'm actually looking forward to the work!

Comment: @Cornyvita Sometimes we just need someone else to tell us what we already know :) I'm very glad to hear it ended well for you, thanks for the update - and congratulations!